# SQL Select dentro de um select com condição

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu possuo 3 tabelas no banco de dados para controlar um "portal de notícias", onde as tabelas tem as seguintes funções:

- noticia -> Tabela com as notícias
- galeria -> Tabela com imagens usadas em notícias
- relacao -> Tabela relacionando as notícias com as imagens

Cada notícia pode ter mais de uma imagem, por isso a segmentação. Eu consegui elaborar um modo de selecionar a notícia e as imagens pertencentes a ela, porém com o uso de foreach, executando assim 2 SELECT, por exemplo:

```
$noticia = "SELECT * FROM noticia";

foreach ($noticia as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];

    $galeria = "SELECT a.* FROM galeria a, relacao b WHERE b.idNoticia = '$id' AND b.id_galeria = a.id";;
}
```

Existem casos em que a notícia pode não ter imagem ainda.

Gostaria de saber se tem algum método de melhorar esse código e realizar toda a consulta em apenas um select, é possível?

Existem outras áreas que eu posso expandir essa mesma lógica, como por exemplo, selecionar as *tags* cadastradas na notícia (segue a mesma lógica, só mudando as tabelas de referência), mas resolvendo este problema, consigo resolver os demais.

Comment: Veja assim: "SELECT a.* FROM galeria a left join relacao b on a.ID = b.ID WHERE b.idNoticia = '$id' "

Comment: Tente dessa forma aqui,  `$galeria = "SELECT a.* FROM galeria a, relacao b JOIN noticia n ON b.idNoticia = n.id WHERE b.id_galeria = a.id";`

Comment: Se der eu coloco a resposta completa...

Comment: @LocalHost mas a ideia seria mesclar o select da `galeria` e `relacao` com o select da noticia, transformando somente em 1. Do modo como você passou ele não resolve essa questão. No caso, primeiro eu preciso carregar a notícia em si, para depois carregar as imagens (caso existam).

Comment: mas no caso eu retirei o noticia e foreach transformei em um select só... Só nao pude testar aqui,mas vou testar aqui...

Comment: @LocalHost mas e a seleção dos dados da tabela noticia?

Comment: Ai seria só adicionar junto ao select `$galeria = "SELECT a.*,n.* FROM galeria a, relacao b JOIN noticia n ON b.idNoticia = n.id WHERE b.id_galeria = a.id";`

Comment: @LocalHost a sim, perfeito. Então, nesse caso eu consegui selecionar, porém, somente as notícias que possuem imagens. As que não possuem não foram selecionadas. Preciso selecionar todas (com/sem imagem) mais as imagens daquelas que possuem.

Comment: Coloca como esta seu banco para ficar melhor de compreender... porque agora buguei aqui kk

Comment: @CelsomTrindade se quer toda noticia, mesmo sem foto, é só usar LEFT JOIN com a tabela de noticias da esquerda. Mais detalhes aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70 - Notar que no caso, você estará fazendo a parte da notícia repetir em todas as fotos, o que é um desperdício de banda do servidor usualmente. Isso que você quer só faz sentido se for pra pegar uma foto só por notícia (tipo foto de capa, por exemplo), e carregar as outras fotos da noticia ao abrir, em um SELECT separado. (e eu já vi solução pras duas situações já respondidas aqui no site, pra falar bem a verdade)

Comment: @Bacco então, apesar de existir outros meios, por questão de recursos, o ideal seria continuar fazendo como demonstrado na minha pergunta?

Comment: Só depende do seu caso em específico. O importante é você entender a diferença de cada uma das maneiras, conforme comentei antes. Usando Join, repete os campos que serão usados uma vez só, mas retorna tudo. Fazendo do seu jeito, são várias requisições. Cada opção tem um "custo", precisa calcular no seu caso real o que compensa mais.